# First frame from captureStream() not sending

Tags: javascript, canvas, mediarecorder, requestframe, capturestream

We're working on a project where people can be in a chat room with their webcams, and they can grab a snapshot of someone's cam at that moment, do some annotations on top of it, and then share that modified picture as if it was their own webcam (like sharing a whiteboard).

Capturing the webcam stream into a canvas element where it can be edited was relatively easy. Finding the canvas element on our page and doing a .getContext('2d') on it, 
Used an open library to add editing tools to it. Grabbing a stream from that canvas was done like so:

```
var canvasToSend = document.querySelector('canvas');
var stream = canvasToSend.captureStream(60);
var room = osTwilioVideoWeb.getConnectedRoom();

var mytrack = null;
room.localParticipant.publishTrack(stream.getTracks()[0]).then((publication) => {
    mytrack = publication.track;
    var videoElement = mytrack.attach();
});
```

This publishes the stream alright, but the first frame will not get sent unless you draw *something else* on the canvas. Let's say you drew 2 circles and then hit Share, the stream will start but will not be shown on the recipients' side unless you draw a line, or another circle, or anything. It seems like it needs a frame *change* for it to send data over.

I was able to force this with developer tools by doing something like context.fill();, but when I tried adding this after the publishing function, even in a then()... no luck.

Any ideas on how to force this "refresh" to happen?

Comment: That all sounds like a Chrome bug. I don't have enough time tonight to dig into it, but even [requestFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack/requestFrame) which should have done just what you want doesn't seem to work... Maybe the best workaround for now would be `ctx.drawImage(canvas);`once the stream is being consumed.

Comment: That's crossed my mind, but the result is the same in Firefox unfortunately. Will try that workaround, I'm just having trouble with the whole "once the stream is being consumed", I haven't found a reliable way to run those functions *only after* the stream begins. I have a feeling they're running before.

Comment: Uh? Can you confirm [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ta0f6g9d/) reproduces the issue on your Firefox? If so, does clicking "requestFrame" draw the frame there? I cannot repro on my FF62 and FF61 on macOs. If it doesn't there may be something in your server side too. I don't know twilio but fast reading the Internets, there seem to be a `participant.on('trackPublished')` and a `participant.on('trackAdded')` event listeners. That's probably where you should refresh the frame (and once again from my tests on Chrome, `gCO='copy'; ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,0)` seems to be the cleanest on Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

So it seems it is expected behavior (and thus would make my FF buggy).

From [the specs](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#methods-0) about the frame request algorithm:

> A new frame is requested from the canvas when *frameCaptureRequested* is *true* and the canvas is painted.

Let's put some emphasis on the "***and*** the canvas as been painted". This means that we need **both** these conditions, and while *captureStream* itself, or its frameRate argument ellapsing or a method like [*requestFrame*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack/requestFrame) would all set the *frameCaptureRequested* flag to true, we still need the new painting...

The specs even have a [note](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#h-note)  stating

> This algorithm results in a captured track not starting until something changes in the canvas.

And Chrome indeed seems to generate an empty *CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack* if the call to *captureStream* has been made after the canvas has been painted.

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas')
  .getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
// let's request a stream from before it gets painted
// (in the same frame)
const stream1 = ctx.canvas.captureStream();
vid1.srcObject = stream1;
// now let's wait that a frame ellapsed
// (rAF fires before next painting, so we need 2 of them)
requestAnimationFrame(()=>
  requestAnimationFrame(()=> {
    const stream2 = ctx.canvas.captureStream();
    vid2.srcObject = stream1;
  })
);
```

```html
<p>stream initialised in the same frame as the drawings (i.e before paiting).</p>
<video id="vid1" controls autoplay></video>
<p>stream initialised after paiting.</p>
<video id="vid2" controls autoplay></video>
```

So to workaround this, you should be able to get a stream with a frame by requesting the stream from the same operation as a first drawing on the canvas, like `stream1` in above example.

Or, you could redraw the canvas context over itself (assuming it is a 2d context) by calling `ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,0)` after having set its globalCompositeOperation to 'copy' to avoid transparency issues.

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas')
  .getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '15px sans-serif';
ctx.fillText('if forced to redraw it should work', 20, 20);
// produce a silent stream again
requestAnimationFrame(() =>
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    const stream = ctx.canvas.captureStream();
    forcePainting(stream);
    vid.srcObject = stream;
  })
);
// beware will work only for canvas intialised with a 2D context
function forcePainting(stream) {
  const ctx = (stream.getVideoTracks()[0].canvas ||
      stream.canvas) // FF has it wrong...
    .getContext('2d');
  const gCO = ctx.globalCompositeOperation;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = gCO;
}
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls autoplay></video>
```